# Expanding and using salt generation code for a php login system

Tags: php, encryption, salt, salt-creation

I am working on a php/mysql login system for a webproject. After looking through SO and alot of articles on the web Ive come up with a basic framework and started writing some code for it.  However Ive come to a bit of an impasse in password encryption.

After a nights worth of reading Ive found out that:

- I should the users password with at least sha1 or sha2
- I should also use a randomly generated salt (this is what I need help with) and append it to the password before encrypting it
- the hashed password and the randomly generated salt should be stored in the database and then queried and combined/encrypted then checked against the users hashed password.

My problem is coming in randomly generating the salt,

Comment: Small remark here: SHA1/2/... is not an encryption algorithm, but a hashing algorithm. Meaning that it's not possible to find the original password from the hash value. Also, in the interest of stopping rainbow table attacks and just as a good security practice, don't hash just once, hash your hash at least 100 times, more if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibilities I can think of:

- Use [mt_rand()](http://php.net/mt_rand) in a loop to pick an ASCII code, get the corresponding character with [chr()](http://php.net/chr%28%29) and [concatenate](http://es.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) to salt.

  This allows to create salts with any length.
- Define a string with available characters, use [mt_rand()](http://php.net/mt_rand) in a loop to pick random positions from it, extract the character in the selected position with [substr()](http://php.net/substr) or [mb_substr()](http://php.net/mb_substr) and [concatenate](http://es.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) to salt.

  This allows to create salts with a chosen character set and length.
- Use a builtin function that generates a random string (e.g. [uniqid()](http://php.net/uniqid)) and optionally hash it.

  This is quick and simple.

I normally use the second option.

Answer (score 0):

uniqid() ?

https://www.php.net/uniqid